# how to deploy yeoman angular-fullstack project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, yeoman, yo

I want to deploy a simple angular projet made with angular fullstack.

https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

I tried :

```
yo angular-fullstack test

grunt build
```

Then, in dist I got 2 folders: server and public.

how to deploy them on a linux server ?

with forever/node  and nginx ???
I want to self host my project.

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1.) **Install nginx**

2.) **Proxy forward nginx** to your node port. See [Digital Oceans How-To](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab).

**nginx.conf**

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

3.) **Start app.js** with node in your dist folder with the correct variables:

```
$ export NODE_ENV=production; export PORT=9000; node dist/server/app.js
```

4.) **Browse to the hostname** configured in nginx in step 2.

In case you get many **404**'s you most likely are using **angular.js in HTML5 mode** and need to re-wire your routes to serve static angular.js content. I described this and how-to tackle many other bugs that you may face in my blog article: "[Continous Integration with Angular Fullstack](http://meshfields.de/continuous-integration-angular-fullstack/)".

Answer (score 6):

You can try pm2 as well which is straightforward and easy, it comes with lots of useful features.

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

```
// Start new node process
$ pm2 start dist/server/app.js

// list all process
$ pm2 list
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're running a mongo db with a host you will need to change the /server/config/environment/production.js uri to match development.js and it should work.

With MongoLab you have something to this effect:
mongodb://user:pass@XXXXX.mongolab.com:XXXXX/yourdatabase

then run the **grunt serve:dist** command in your app directory.

This worked for me.

Answer (score -5):

Install `generator-angular-fullstack:`

```
npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack
```

Make a new directory, and `cd` into it:

```
mkdir my-new-project && cd $_
```

Run `yo angular-fullstack`, optionally passing an app name:

```
yo angular-fullstack [app-name]
```

Run `grunt` for building, grunt`serve for preview, and`grunt serve:dist` for a preview of the built app